# add external .csv files to magento to update product details

Tags: product, attributes, csv, sku

I want to add an extra attribute value to all products.

so we are planning to update through import products using .csv

please give me the procedure to add only one attribute values.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the attribute in the admin area by navigating to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes. Then in your csv file add the attribute ID to the header of the column containing the value. Also ensure that you have a SKU column and then import the CSV using dataflow profiles but ensure that you match the 2 columns to the corresponding attributes. An example of the CSV could be:

"sku","new_attribute_id"
"SKU001","New Attribute Value"
"SKU002","New Attribute Value"
"SKU003","New Attribute Value"

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. for that i have to create new profile. am i right?

Comment: You can create a new profile or you can just use the standard product import/export dataflow profiles. Just make sure you map the fields in your CSV using the mapped fields option. Hope this helps you out.